# How to get correct floating-point precision in Qt and C++?

Tags: c++, qt, floating-accuracy

I am studying Qt, I find it really amazing and a bit easier because I've already used MFC in Microsoft.

I've developed a scientific calculator for educational use. But what faced me is:

I want float high precision like in real-world calculators so after searching I've found this function:

```
    long double ldRes =  std::sqrt(3);
    QMessageBox m;
    m.settext(QString::number(ldRes, 'g', 30));
    m.exec();
```

The output:

```
1.73205080756887719317660412344
```

While the output, according the [The Casio Calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/calculator), of the same operation to the same precision, should be:

```
1.73205080756887729352744634151
```

So it is apparent that the result is not the same so can anyone advise me how to get correct float-precision in my applications using Qt? or any other library?

Should I use GMP MPIR MPFR?

Thank you!

Comment: How much precision do you want? 10 decimal digits? 20? Arbitrary?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Qt but with the floating point (IEEE 754 standard), there are many libraries that handle the implementation of these operations without losing precision since they do not implement the standard that you could use.

Comment: What "other calculators"?

Comment: DUPE OF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @selbie: Not really, no.

Comment: If this is Visual Studio I think `long double` is the same as `double`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: For example the casio calculator: https://keisan.casio.com/calculator

Comment: Yes to produce an application like that calculator, you may want to use a large math library like GMP or Boost::Multiprecision

Comment: @drescherjm I hear ya, but since the result starts to deviate at ~15-17 decimal significant figures, either the implementation's `sqrt` impl is badly internally broken, or the types differ on the OP's platform

Comment: Granted, I haven't ruled out Qt's output being the culprit

Comment: Also I'm assuming `res` is `ldRes`

Comment: @Maestro Note its name, "high precision" calculator

Answer (score 5):

When you use `std::sqrt` and pass a `double` (well, an `int`, which will end up being converted to `double`), the result is a `double`.

Converting that result to `long double` achieves nothing but gaining a ton of low-value bits with no relation to the result of the square-root operation!

I don't know what "other calculators" you're using, but something about the difference between the two approaches leads to those different results.

[`std::sqrtl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) works with `long double`s, or you can pass a `long double` argument to `std::sqrt` which picks the right overload.

```
// Effectively equivalent:
long double a = std::sqrtl(3);
long double b = std::sqrtl(3);
long double c = std::sqrt(3.0L);
```

Now, your calculation has the precision of a `long double` from end to end, and ought to be mathematically correct to that level of precision.

Comment: Converting a `double` to a `long double` does not “[gain] a ton of low-value bits” except for zero bits. A conversion to a more precise type does not change the value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What? You said it yourself: zero bits (by "low-value" I'm referring to their low magnitude, the fact that they are on the least-significant side of the overall value). And those zero bits are _wrong_. They make the result mathematically incorrect. No, the value isn't different from what it was as a `double`, but it _is_ different from what it will be in any tool that gives that mathematical result to that precision correctly. And that's what I said: _"achieves nothing but gaining a ton of low-value bits **with no relation to the result of the square-root operation**"_

Comment: The language in the answer should be more precise and explicit. As humans use language, “digits” or “bits” may refer to either to significant non-zero digits or bits or to formal bits in a representation. This is particularly so in the case of floating-point discussion, where people sometimes refer to unexpected or incompletely understood values has having various noise or “randomness” in the low bits. Even if you are using language in a specific deliberate way, readers cannot know that unless they are told or at least there are indications of it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Feel free to write your own. I stand by my wording - nobody else seems to have misinterpreted it. But I do appreciate your feedback. Take care!